# 19.10 Cannot add Microsoft exchange account on Online Accounts

Tags: unity, 19.10, settings, online-accounts, ms-exchange

The screenshot says it all. I can't add a Microsoft Echange accounts as there is a red cross sign on the microsoft echange option of the online accounts.
[image: Screenshot of Online Accounts]

Click it, and I get
[image: Fields of Microsoft Exchange option]

Which is weird, it seems that all the other people are getting `[connect]` button on top right or so.

I installed `evolution` and `evolution-ews`.

I don't know if it matters but I use unity.

Comment: Maybe your window is cropped somehow. Can you try to move it to the left or maximize it?

Comment: @FedonKadifeli The window is as is. It seems to be cropped but that's the entire thing.

Comment: Any news on this?